# How can I embed the AJAX output of JS in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

It's becoming a nightmare for me solving this problem. I am developing an app using phonegap. I have used highcharts in it for Graphs. The graph is coming properly but not the tooltip in the graph. Please check the code below, I need this code to be able to show the tooltip with proper data. There has to be a loop of the following code and it has to be for every user or series in the graph. So I have ran a for loop in PHP and saved it in a variable and got the whole output of the loop using AJAX in a JSON format.

When I use the variable in the Javascript code in which I have saved the AJAX output, it just doesn't do anything but if I alert than it alerts the exact code which I want to make tooltip work. I have tried eval() also but no benefit. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

**Loop Code**

```
        $toolTip = '';

        for($i=0;$i<$teamControllerW->total_user;$i++){
            $toolTip .= "var chart = $('#team_containerWF').highcharts();";
            $toolTip .= "var figures".$i." = [".join($teamControllerW->new_yAxesData1[$i], ",") ."]; ";
            $toolTip .= "var fatVals".$i." = [". join($teamControllerW->fatVal[$i], ',') ."]; ";
            $toolTip .= "var weightVals".$i." = [". join($teamControllerW->weightVal[$i], ',') ."]; ";
            $toolTip .= "var result_playing_dates = [". join($teamControllerW->new_playing_dates_data[$i], ',') ."]; ";
            $toolTip .= "
            $.each(figures".$i.", function (j, figure".$i.") {
                 var curDanger = (figure".$i."[0] - danger[0][0]) * delta + danger[0][1];
                 var play_date = false;
                 for (var k = 0; k < result_playing_dates.length ; k ++ ) {
                    if (figure".$i."[0] == result_playing_dates[k]) {
                        play_date = true;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 ";
                 $toolTip .= "if (figure".$i."[1] > curDanger) {
                    if (play_date) {
                        if (chart.series[".$i."].data[j] && chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic) {
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic.attr({ fill: '#a31515' });
                             chart.series[".$i."].data[j].update({
                             fatVal : fatVals".$i."[j],
                             weightVal : weightVals".$i."[j],
                             marker:{
                                fillColor: '#a31515',
                                radius: 6,
                                states: {
                                      hover: {
                                         fillColor: '#a31515',
                                         lineColor: '#a31515',
                                         radius: 10
                                      }
                                   }
                                }
                             });
                        }
                     }
                     else {
                        if (chart.series[".$i."].data[j] && chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic) {
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic.attr({ fill: 'red' });
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].update({
                            fatVal : fatVals".$i."[j],
                            weightVal : weightVals".$i."[j],
                            marker:{
                               fillColor: 'red',
                               states: {
                                     hover: {
                                        fillColor: 'red',
                                        lineColor: 'red'                                    
                                     }
                                  }
                               }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (play_date) {
                        if (chart.series[".$i."].data[j] && chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic) {
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic.attr({ fill: '#02491a' });
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].update({
                            fatVal : fatVals".$i."[j],
                            weightVal : weightVals".$i."[j],
                            marker:{
                                 fillColor: '#02491a',
                                 radius: 6,
                                 states: {
                                       hover: {
                                        fillColor: '#02491a',
                                        lineColor: '#02491a',
                                        radius: 10
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                            });
                        }
                     }
                     else {
                        if (chart.series[".$i."].data[j] && chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic) {
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].graphic.attr({ fill: 'green' });
                            chart.series[".$i."].data[j].update({
                            fatVal : fatVals".$i."[j],
                            weightVal : weightVals".$i."[j],
                            marker:{
                               fillColor: 'green',
                               states: {
                                     hover: {
                                        fillColor: 'green',
                                        lineColor: 'green'                                  
                                     }
                                  }
                               }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                 }
            });
            ";
      }//end for
```

**I'm calling the data like this**

```
    var teamweighinLMgameAction = window.localStorage.getItem("teamweighinLMgameAction");
    AGWeigh = JSON.parse(teamweighinLMgameAction);
    var toolTip = AGWeigh.toolTip;

    alert(toolTip);//On alert it comes fine

    if(data_avail=='yes') { //check if data available
        var danger = myDangerLine,
        deltaX = danger[1][0] - danger[0][0],
        deltaY = danger[1][1] - danger[0][1],
        delta = deltaY / deltaX;

        alert("In: "+toolTip);//the data also alerts fine here

        toolTip; //This is the place where I need the loop output but it nothing comes up

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this sounds like "Loop Code" being result of an AJAX call has passed js code "var chart = $('#team_containerWF').highcharts();..."!! **However, this will never get executed by the main page**. An AJAX result being passed should ideally be JSON/XML and then only contain name value pairs of data. Such that your main code being viewed would:

> 1. validate those name value pairs
> 2. execute its own code to render the graph based on those name value pairs

Therefore, my recommendation is try to structure it that firstly Main page handles the logic for display in Javascript, and AJAX pages in PHP handle the logic for pulling data and not display.

Also you could provide us with a bit more detail on the structure of your project. Label your code e.g. index.php getChartPlayingDates.php?